# How do GPL 2, 3 and other copy-left licenses apply in cases of "software as a service" (SaaS) systems?

Tags: software, open-source-software, gpl

GPL-style licenses are pretty effective at ensuring the underlying code cannot contribute to proprietary binary programs.  But in the contemporary world of SaaS, are there not many ways around this?

For example, a highly unethical SaaS company could use GPL-ed code in one specific microservice at the company.  This may not constitute the code being "part of" a proprietary program, because the microservice is far removed from the JavaScript that actually runs on the user's browser.

Comment: Please do not answer in comments